# mongo_mapper_acts_as_versioned failing when saving a Time type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongomapper, bson, rails-3.0.10

I am trying to set up versioning on my mongomapper model using the https://github.com/Bramanga/mongo_mapper_acts_as_versioned gem that I forked. However, whenever I try to save my Finding model, it fails if I try to save it with a Time type (which I have to use because MongoDB only supports utc times, and not dates).

Model:

```
class Finding
  require 'carrierwave/orm/mongomapper'
  include MongoMapper::Document
  ensure_index 'finding.document'
  plugin MongoMapper::Acts::Versioned 

  attr_accessible :found_date, :target_date, :abated_date

  key             :found_date,          Time
  key             :target_date,         Time
  key             :abated_date,         Time
  
  belongs_to      :client
  many            :uploads, :dependent => :destroy
  many            :documents, :dependent => :destroy

  timestamps!

  def found_date=(date)
    if date.present?
      self[:found_date] = Chronic.parse(date).utc.beginning_of_day
    else
      self[:found_date] = nil
    end
  end

  def target_date=(date)
    if date.present?
      self[:target_date] = Chronic.parse(date).utc.beginning_of_day
    else
      self[:target_date] = nil
    end
  end

  def abated_date=(date)
    if date.present?
      self[:abated_date] = Chronic.parse(date).utc.beginning_of_day
    else
      self[:abated_date] = nil
    end
  end
end
```

Terminal output:

> Loading development environment (Rails 3.0.10)
>
> [1](https://github.com/Bramanga/mongo_mapper_acts_as_versioned) pry(main)> finding = Client.first.findings.build

=> <#Finding _id: BSON::ObjectId('4fc67c8f4e484f267c000002'), client_id: BSON::ObjectId('4f7119884e484f25bd005ee8'), custom_fields: {}, legacy_attachments: [], tags: []>

> [2] pry(main)> finding.save

=> true

> [3] pry(main)> finding.found_date = "12/24/2012"

=> "12/24/2012"

> [4] pry(main)> finding.save

**BSON::InvalidDocument: ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone is not currently supported; use a UTC Time instance instead.
from /home/bramanga/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@actionlog/gems/bson-1.6.2/lib/bson/bson_c.rb:24:in `serialize'**

I'm not sure how to fix this. Maybe I'm just doing it wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: Your code lines work for me if I comment out the "plugin" and "many" lines, so I really haven't tested whether MongoMapper::Acts::Versioned is related to your problem.  Can you post your Gemfile?  It's difficult and time consuming to guess at the gems and plugins that you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed my own issue after forking the repo. My solution is [here](https://github.com/Bramanga/mongo_mapper_acts_as_versioned.git).

The issue is related to `mongodb`'s supported date types. It only supports a `UTC` timestamp format. I added my own `escape_mongo` method to convert to a safe `timestamp` type before being persisted to the database:

```
def escape_mongo(obj)       
    obj.is_a?(Date) || obj.is_a?(Time) ? Date.to_mongo(obj) : obj   
end
```